# Should I be mean and pop my villagers' balloons?

Tags: android, happy-street

Sometimes my villagers walk around with balloons. If I tap them (which pops them) I get 40 coins. Is there any benefit to letting them keep the balloons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you surely already know, you get 40 coins for popping a balloon. However, if you’re willing to wait, your villagers never take the balloon inside their home. If you pop a balloon before it floats away, you’ll get 100 coins, instead.